# Is there a Javascript library that provides canvas and toolbox features

Tags: javascript, node.js, react

I have been giving the task to develop a web application that will allow end users to design their own Sign.  Users can select templates (different canvas sizes) add text, images etc.. and this will show the price in the bottom right with a button to checkout.

an example of some such site is this:

https://www.signomatic.co.uk/signomatic/

what JavaScript frameworks would you use to accomplish such a task?  Are there any JS frameworks that you could recommend that provide a toolbox to work with the canvas like the above example.